# Uncaught TypeError: THREE.UVMapping is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm using the R87 version of three.js,and this error has occurred.But I don't use R59 for this problem.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3683

According to doob: "THREE.UVMapping is no longer a function."

Maybe you're using a later version of three.js than the code your trying to run was written for?